# Boost search score from data in another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, lucene, mongodb-atlas

I use Atlas Search to return a list of documents (using Mongoose):

```
const searchResults = await Resource.aggregate()
   .search({
       text: {
           query: searchQuery,
           path: ["title", "tags", "link", "creatorName"], 
       },
   }
   )
   .match({ approved: true })
   .addFields({
       score: { $meta: "searchScore" }
   })
   .exec();
```

These resources can be **up and downvoted by users** (like questions on Stackoverflow). I want to **boost the search score depending on these votes**.

I can use the [boost](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/scoring/) operator for that.

**Problem: The votes are not a property of the `Resource` document. Instead, they are stored in a separate collection:**

```
const resourceVoteSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: { type: String },
    userId: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    resourceId: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    upDown: { type: String, required: true },
```

After I get my search results above, I fetch the votes separately and add them to each search result:

```
for (const resource of searchResults) {
    const resourceVotes = await ResourceVote.find({ resourceId: resource._id }).exec();
    resource.votes = resourceVotes
}
```

**I then subtract the downvotes from the upvotes on the client and show the final number in the UI.**

**How can I incorporate this vote points value into the score of the search results? Do I have to reorder them on the client?**

**Edit:**

Here is my updated code. The only part that's missing is **letting the resource votes boost the search score, while at the same time keeping all `resource-votes` documents in the `votes` field** so that I can access them later. I'm using Mongoose syntax but an answer with normal MongoDB syntax will work for me:

```
const searchResults = await Resource.aggregate()
            .search({
                compound: {
                    should: [
                        {
                            wildcard: {
                                query: queryStringSegmented,
                                path: ["title", "link", "creatorName"],
                                allowAnalyzedField: true,
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            wildcard: {
                                query: queryStringSegmented,
                                path: ["topics"],
                                allowAnalyzedField: true,
                                score: { boost: { value: 2 } },
                            }
                        }
                        ,
                        {
                            wildcard: {
                                query: queryStringSegmented,
                                path: ["description"],
                                allowAnalyzedField: true,
                                score: { boost: { value: .2 } },
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
            )
            .lookup({
                from: "resourcevotes",
                localField: "_id",
                foreignField: "resourceId",
                as: "votes",
            })
            .addFields({
                searchScore: { $meta: "searchScore" },
            })
            .facet({
                approved: [
                    { $match: matchFilter },
                    { $skip: (page - 1) * pageSize },
                    { $limit: pageSize },
                ],
                resultCount: [
                    { $match: matchFilter },
                    { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
                ],
                uniqueLanguages: [{ $group: { _id: null, all: { $addToSet: "$language" } } }],
            })
            .exec();
```

Comment: For this you can use ['$lookup'](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: @nimrodserok Works wonderfully and much faster than the manual loop + `find` I did before. If you want, you can post an answer (with normal MongoDB syntax) and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done with one query only, looking similar to:

```
Resource.aggregate([
  {
    $search: {
      text: {
        query: "searchQuery",
        path: ["title", "tags", "link", "creatorName"]
      }
    }
  },
  {$match: {approved: true}},
  {$addFields: {score: {$meta: "searchScore"}}},
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "ResourceVote",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "resourceId",
      as: "votes"
    }
  }
])
```

Using the `$lookup` step to get the votes from the `ResourceVote` collection

If you want to use the votes to boost the score, you can replace the above `$lookup` step with something like:

```
{
    $lookup: {
      from: "resourceVote",
      let: {resourceId: "$_id"},
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {$expr: {$eq: ["$resourceId", "$$resourceId"]}}
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: 0,
            sum: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$upDown", "up"]}, 1, -1]}}
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "votes"
    }
  },
  {$addFields: { votes: {$arrayElemAt: ["$votes", 0]}}},
  {
    $project: {
      "wScore": {
        $ifNull: [
          {$multiply: ["$score", "$votes.sum"]},
          "$score"
        ]
      },
      createdAt: 1,
      score: 1
    }
  }
```

As you can see on [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kkdvZvPPpA0)

**EDIT**: If you want to keep the votes on the results, you can do something like:

```
db.searchResults.aggregate([
   {
    $lookup: {
      from: "ResourceVote",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "resourceId",
      as: "votes"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "votesCount": {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$votes",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {$add: ["$$value", {$cond: [{$eq: ["$$this.upDown", "up"]}, 1, -1]}]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "wScore": {
        $add: [{$multiply: ["$votesCount", 0.1]}, "$score"]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

As can be seen [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Iidg1zyGHBo)

Comment: Thank you very much! The `$lookup` part works  However, I don't know how to use it to boost the search score, since `$search` has to run before `$lookup`. Should I modify the search score and sort the array manually (in JS code) after the aggregation?

Comment: It can be done inside the query. If you provide some example of the results of the first step, I'll show you how

Comment: What do you mean by examples of the results of the first step? The `ResourceVote`s contain a `userId` (the voter), a `resourceId` (the voted object) and a value called `upDown` which states if it's an *up* or *down* vote (as a string value).
I want to boost the score depending on the net value of votes (ups minus downs).

Comment: Thanks for the update! This looks quite complicated. I'm considering doing the vote-based score calculations in JS code for simplicity. What do you think about that? It's quite fast right now but maybe it'll be slower when I have a large database.

Comment: I don't find this query complicated. It is probably more efficient than the js. The `$lookup` is already loops over the `resourceVotes` anyway, So I would keep the new one. The two other steps are extremely light...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I will implement it tomorrow with a fresh mind!

Comment: I found another important reason to add the search score within the `aggregate` and that is pagination! My old setup would calculate the final search score **after** the `limit` operator which of course I don't want. So thank you again!

Comment: I have trouble implementing your solution because the `$project` call is happening outside the `$lookup` block. Doesn't this interfere with the rest of my dataset?

Comment: Why is this a problem? Can't you do it like I did?

Comment: If not, we can put these stages inside the `$lookup`

Comment: I thought `$project` removes all other fields from the dataset, doesn't it? I will try it again step by step later and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: It does not change your data on the the db, just your query results.

Comment: Thank you, your approach works. But now I only get the sum of the votes, right? I also need access to the resource vote documents' data. Do I need to add both lookups separately?

Comment: No need for two lookups. You can just take the `$group` step out of the '$lookup` pipline, so the `$lookup` will return the raw data. Then you can use '$facet` if you want to format this data in more than one way

Comment: Then I can also rever the lookup syntax back to the previous one without `let` and `pipeline`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. It is less efficient to group outside the lookup, but if you need the original results, then this is what needs to be done

Comment: I can't get this to work, there is just too much stuff going on. Could you take a look at the new code in my edited question and help me figure this out?

Comment: If you will create an example on mongodb playground, similar to the one in my answer, but including a sample of your data before the lookup, I can continue from there

Comment: Mong Playground doesn't seem to work for me. I get a `HostUnreachable` error.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/kkdvZvPPpA0

Comment: As soon as I change the query I always get `query failed: (HostUnreachable) PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Remote error from mongot :: caused by :: Error connecting to localhost:28000 (127.0.0.1:28000) :: caused by :: Connection refused`

Comment: Also, I don't wanna multiply the score by the number of votes. I want to add `0.1` for each vote. I'll have to find a different solution.

Comment: You can use the same solution with a minor change

Comment: Why did you removed your score to the solution?

Comment: The score is still there, I removed the accepted answer because the problem isn't solved yet and I don't want to discourage others from posting a solution. But I'm very thankful for your help so far!

Comment: But I told you I can adjust the solution easily, if you just provide few example documents after the first `$lookup`

Comment: I wasn't able to transform my Mongoose syntax into normal MongoDB syntax

Comment: Does this answers: https://mongoplayground.net/p/6WxyWNoTBRH ?

Comment: I'll try it out later today and let you know. Thank you!