# Get a list of unique values from MongoDB Atlas Search before match filters are applied

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I use MongoDB Atlas Search to search through a list of resources in my database (I'm using Mongoose, hence the slightly different syntax):

```
const allApprovedSearchResults = await Resource.aggregate([{
    $search: {
        compound: {
            should: [
                {
                    wildcard: {
                        query: queryStringSegmented,
                        path: ["title", "link", "creatorName"],
                        allowAnalyzedField: true,
                    }
                },
                {
                    wildcard: {
                        query: queryStringSegmented,
                        path: ["topics"],
                        allowAnalyzedField: true,
                        "score": { "boost": { "value": 2 } },
                    }
                }
                ,
                    {
                    wildcard: {
                        query: queryStringSegmented,
                        path: ["description"],
                        allowAnalyzedField: true,
                        score: { "boost": { "value": .2 } },
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}])
    .match(matchFilter)
    .exec();

const uniqueLanguagesInSearchResults = [...new Set(allApprovedSearchResults.map(resource => resource.language))];
```

The last line retrieves all unique languages in the results set. **However, I want a list of all the languages before `.match(matchFilter)` is applied.** Is there a way to do this without running a second search without the filters?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this syntax, but on the regular syntax you can use `$facet` or `$setWindowFields`

Comment: @nimrodserok Thank you, `$facet` looks exactly like what I need! Maybe you also know the answer to my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71968097/boost-search-score-from-data-in-another-collection

Comment: @nimrodserok I tried with `$facet` first, but it threw an error when I used it together with `$search`. Then I tried `$setWindowFields` together with `$addToSet` but it only seems to work on the single document level. But I need a set of languages for the **whole result set** (before `$match` is applied)

Comment: $setWindowFields is for all results

Comment: I can write you a response using the normal syntax. You can use it with mongoose...

Comment: @nimrodserok But how do I get the languages of all documents into a single array or set? I have to combine `§setWindowFields` with something.

Comment: @nimrodserok That would be awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `$facet` after the `$search`:

```
.aggregate([
  {
    $search: {
        compound: {
            should: [
                {
                    wildcard: {
                        query: queryStringSegmented,
                        path: ["title", "link", "creatorName"],
                        allowAnalyzedField: true,
                    }
                },
                {
                    wildcard: {
                        query: queryStringSegmented,
                        path: ["topics"],
                        allowAnalyzedField: true,
                        "score": { "boost": { "value": 2 } },
                    }
                }
                ,
                    {
                    wildcard: {
                        query: queryStringSegmented,
                        path: ["description"],
                        allowAnalyzedField: true,
                        score: { "boost": { "value": .2 } },
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
  {
    "$facet": {
      "filter": [
        {$match: matchFilter}
      ],
      "allLanguages ": [
        {$group: {_id: 0, all: {$addToSet: '$language'}}}, //<- replace '$language' with real field name
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

You did not provide a structure so I'm assuming 'language' is the field name. The `$facet` creates a fork - one part called 'filter' will contain only the filtered results, while the other one, called allLanguages, will contain a set of all languages, regardless of the filter.You can add `$project` steps inside each `$facet` pipeline to format the data.

According to the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/query-syntax/), it should work :)

Comment: Awesome, it works. Thank you very much! The return value of the `aggregate` call becomes an array with a `length` of `1`, is that correct? Does this length ever change?

Comment: Yes, but not on this query. In this query the `$facet` creates an object, i.e. one document. If you remove the facet, just for fun, and apply only the filter with '$match' you can have many answers.

Comment: Can you answer this one as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72263366/mongodb-atlas-boost-search-score-from-external-list-of-words