# MongoDB: sort by product of textScore and other value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, node-mongodb-native

Is it possible to sort text-search results using a projection that combines `{$meta: "textScore"}` with some other values? Each of our documents has a quality (pagerank) score, and I would like to sort results using the product of the text-match and the pagerank for the document:

```js
var cursor = packages.find(query).project({
    score: {$multiply: [{$meta: "textScore"}, '$_pagerank']},
    Foo: 1, 
    Bar:1,
}).sort({score:-1}).limit(limit);
```

The results for the above query do contain the expected `score` values, but the output is not sorted at all. I tested that sorting does work based on only the textScore `.sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}})` however that does not take the pagerank of the document into account.

Is it possible at all to sort in mongodb using a projected value? We are currently using mongodb 4.4.

Comment: Why don't simply construct an aggregation pipeline like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lOpb6EeBrZL)?

Comment: I think that comes down to the same thing, with the same problem?

Comment: would be helpful if we can have some sample data and your text index so that we can try to reproduce your issue

Comment: Of course it is possible. You may want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71968097/boost-search-score-from-data-in-another-collection/71997426?noredirect=1#comment127418844_71997426)

Comment: @JeroenOoms aggregation is very different to find queries. Please try what ray suggested, don't assume it won't work.